# Get Address of Maximum Value Within Range

Tags: excel

[image]

I have the following Excel file, as well as a separate tab with a long list of Last Names. Assume the names are in column A.

If the maximum (column L) is greater than 60, I've put an "X" in column M. For each last name, if the maximum > 60, I'd like to return the race with the maximum.

So for Smith, i'd like to return White, for Johnson I'd like to return nothing.

I'd like to use the "X" column so that an end user can easily change the 60% assumption.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this following formula in Cell M2 and drag down, should return what you want instead of X

```
=IF(MAX(A2:K2)>60,VLOOKUP($A$1,A:K,MATCH(MAX(A2:K2),A2:K2,0),FALSE),"")
```